# msxml XMLHTTP for large json object works very slow on IE8 and quite good on Firefox - why?

Tags: ajax, performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I am creating an XMLHTTP object in Firefox and IE8 and i transfer a very large amount of data (json). In Firefox it renders it in 5 seconds, in IE8 it takes 30 seconds.

Is there any way to make IE8 XMLHTTP works faster?

Here is  my code for creating the XHR object:

```
function createRequestObject2()
{
var http_request = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{ //: Mozilla, Safari,...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(http_request.overrideMimeType)
    {
        //: set type accordingly to anticipated content type
        //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{ //: IE
    try
    {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
         try
        {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }
}
if(!http_request)
{
    alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
}

return http_request;
}
```

Here is how i use the XHR:

```
       http = createRequestObject2();
       http.open('GET', encodeURI(action), true);
            http.onreadystatechange = results;
            http.send(null);
            inwork = true;
            viewLoading();

            //: search results handling
            function results()
            {
                /*console.log("do_search.results[ " +
                        'Results return ' + http.readyState
                     + " ]"
                );*/
                if(http.readyState != 4)
                    return;

                inwork = false;

                if(http.status != 200)
                {
                    //setStatusLine(httpapplicant.statusText);
                    return;
                }

                //: evaluate
                var data = eval('(' + http.responseText + ')');

                //: add data to the table
                applicant_list = new dogtable(data, table1_options, $$('dog_results'));

                hideLoading();
            } //function results
```

Comment: Can you show something of your transfer code (JS and server-side technology)? I can only see how you make an instance of XMLHTTPRequest. By the way, in this case IE8 will very likely use XMLHttpRequest() (which is supported from IE7 onwards) instead of making an ActiveXObject.

Comment: We narrowed the problem to the XML HTTP request. This is where the major time is spent. Currently to find the problem, i don't do anything with the returned data, and the server code is in PHP is same for firefox and IE, so it's not there the problem. I edit and added how i use the XHR itself.

Comment: You already incorporated logging of readyState, which is good. Which readyState is shown before it hangs? No idea, but for instance, if it's 4, it means the transfer doesn't slow down on IE.